# Formatting with time.strptime() throws an error

Tags: python, datetime

I'm trying to convert the following date (which is a string) to a datetime object:

```
Fri, 26 Apr 2013 12:00:00 +0000
```

So what I did is throw the +0000 value out and then convert it to a datetime object using the following code:

```
published = entry['published']
print published
published = published[:-6]
print published
published = time.strptime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S",str(published))
```

Which then throws an exception saying the given value is not in the right format

```
Fri, 26 Apr 2013 12:00:00 +0000
Fri, 26 Apr 2013 12:00:00
        C:\Python27\python.exe 
    C:/obfuscated.py
        Traceback (most recent call last):
        Fri, 26 Apr 2013 12:00:00 +0000
          File "C:/obfuscated.py", line 17, in <module>
        Fri, 26 Apr 2013 12:00:00
            class MyClass(object):
          File "C:/obfuscated.py", line 38, in MyClass
            published = time.strptime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S",str(published))
          File "C:\Python27\lib\_strptime.py", line 467, in _strptime_time
            return _strptime(data_string, format)[0]
          File "C:\Python27\lib\_strptime.py", line 325, in _strptime
            (data_string, format))
        ValueError: time data '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S' does not match format 'Fri, 26 Apr 2013 12:00:00'
```

I'm not sure why this fails as the datetime stringformat seems right to me.

Comment: Read the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strptime)! The error message is actually pretty clear (time data 'xxx' does not match format 'yyy')

Comment: Yea, stupid mistake ><

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the parameters round the wrong way, the format string should be the second argument.

Try:

```
published = time.strptime(str(published),"%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S")
```

Comment: No worries. You might want to consider accepting my answer if it resolved your problem. Thanks